# Как заставить бота телеграм удалять свои же сообщения?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Хочу, чтобы бот (TelegramLongPollingBot) периодически писал в беседу, что он онлайн и при этом удалял прошлое такое свое оповещение. Код для удаления старого сообщения:

```java
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {   
   if (update.getMessage().getText().equals("Bot is online"))
      {
         //пауза несколько минут
         DeleteMessage deleteMessage = new DeleteMessage();
         deleteMessage.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId());
         deleteMessage.setMessageId(update.getMessage().getMessageId());
         execute(deleteMessage);
      }
}
```

Оказалось, что метод onUpdateReceived() вообще не перехватывает сообщения самого бота (но мои сообщения "Bot is online" удаляются).

upd. В мануале нашел:
Why doesn't my bot see messages from other bots?
Bots talking to each other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome loops. To avoid this, we decided that **bots will not be able to see messages from other bots** regardless of mode.

Но ведь для удаления сообщения нужно знать его id, а до отправки id неизвестен. Как мне решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Можно узнать id сообщения при его отправке. Решение:

```java
public void sendMsg(String text) 
    {
        SendMessage message = new SendMessage().setChatId(chatId).setText(text);        
            Message sentOutMessage=execute(message);
            if (text.equals("Bot is online")) 
              {
                DeleteMessage deleteMessage = new DeleteMessage();
                deleteMessage.setChatId(sentOutMessage.getChatId());
                deleteMessage.setMessageId(sentOutMessage.getMessageId());                
                //пауза
                execute(deleteMessage);
              }       
    }
```